My Javascript and CSS aren't running properly in HTML
I was trying to build a portfolio for mobile device but I got some problem in my CSS and Js code which I linked to the HTML via link. Most of the CSS works fine but js doesn't run a bit. I have my 3 files* (html, css & js) in a folder.
When I set "display-flex" clsss is the CSS code externally, id didn't run with Js.
Talking about my js which I linked to the HTML, it didn't work. When I add a onclick function in the external js code, I got an* error which was something like " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null ". So I had to remove the js link and directly write it in the HTML
Here is the HTML code:


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Page title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <style type="text/css" media="all">

      .display-flex{

       display: flex;

       height: 5vh;

      }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <header>

      <div class="inner-header">

        <div class="main-logo-area center-box">

          Abdullah

        </div>

        <div class="menu-area center-box">

          <button id="menu-button">Menu</button>

        </div>

      </div>

    </header>

    <ul class="menu-elements center-box">

     <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>

     <li><a href="#About Me">About Me</a></li>

     <li><a href="#Contract Me">Contract Me</a></li>

     <li id="dark-mode-switch">Dark Mode</li>

    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

      let menu_button = document.getElementById("menu-button");

      let menu_elements = document.querySelector(".menu-elements");

      menu_button.onclick = ()=> {

        menu_elements.classList.toggle("display-flex");

        console.log(menu_elements)

      }

      

    </script>

</body>

</html>

CSS:


*{

  background-color: #00ccff3c;

  box-sizing: border-box;

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

  list-style: none;

  overflow: hidden;

}

.center-box {

  display: flex;

  justify-content: center;

  align-items: center;

}

.display-none {

  display: none;

}

.display-flex {

  display: flex;

}

.display {

  display: block;

}

header {

  width: 100vw;

  height: 10vh;

  display: flex;

  justify-content: space-around;

}

.inner-header {

  width: 95vw;

  display: flex;

  justify-content: space-between;

}

.main-logo-area {

  color: #dbe4e6;

}

.menu-area button {

  

}

.menu-elements {

  justify-content: space-around!important;

  height: 0vh;

  display: none;

}

And the Js:
l
et menu_button = document.getElementById("menu-button");

let menu_elements = document.querySelector(".menu-elements");

menu_button.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{

  alert("heijj")

})

So, how am I suppose to fix those issues. I have this problem over and over again. I just don't know what I have done wrong.

The most likely thing is that you are running the JS before the HTML is loaded. Put the JS after the HTML.

Add the defer attribute to your script tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#defer or place the script tag right before the closing body tag.

Or alternatively, take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event

Simple wrap your JS code into window.onload = function() { //CODE HERE }
And use it as external js file in header.
Hope it will helps.
See below:


window.onload = function() {
  let menu_button = document.getElementById("menu-button");
  let menu_elements = document.querySelector(".menu-elements");
  menu_button.onclick = ()=> {
    menu_elements.classList.toggle("display-flex");
    console.log(menu_elements)
  }
}
*{
  background-color: #00ccff3c;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.center-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.display-none {
  display: none;
}

.display-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.display {
  display: block;
}

header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.inner-header {
  width: 95vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-logo-area {
  color: #dbe4e6;
}

.menu-area button {
}

.menu-elements {
  justify-content: space-around!important;
  display: none;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
      .display-flex{
       display: flex;
       height: 5vh;
      }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
      <div class="inner-header">
        <div class="main-logo-area center-box">
          Abdullah
        </div>
        <div class="menu-area center-box">
          <button id="menu-button">Menu</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <ul class="menu-elements center-box">
     <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#About Me">About Me</a></li>
     <li><a href="#Contract Me">Contract Me</a></li>
     <li id="dark-mode-switch">Dark Mode</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>




Why wait for the entire window "load" to query the DOM and add event listeners? This is not the way to do it. Also, a click event can happen long before the window loads, making your app feel pretty broken.

His JS code in the header was not working but in footer it was. So, wrapping the small js code in window.onload helps in this. But adding defer attribute also does the job. Defer also works in a similar way as it specifies that script executes only after the page has finished parsing.

Even https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event is better than window.onload. Also prefer the use of window.addEventListener instead if the overriding on* handlers.
